# Monotouch.Dialog, trying to get EntryElement.ShouldReturn += () => {...}; to work

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I want to add an event handler to the "go" button on the UIKeyboard that appears when entering into an EntryElement. Here is my code

```
EntryElement cPassword;
//
cPassword = new EntryElement (" ", "Password", "", true) {
    ReturnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Go
};
//
cPassword.ShouldReturn += () => { Login (); };
```

The Login method return void and performs a basic logging operation with the entry details provided by the user.

```
private void Login ()
{
    // Do login stuff
    //
}
```

But I think it requires a method of return type func as this is the error message I get when trying to use the current code:

```
Not all code paths return a value in anonymous method of type 'System.Func<bool>' 
(CS1643)
```

This is the first time I've come up against this type of thing, never seen func<> before :/ and hope that someone could point me in the right direction to using it correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your anonymous method should return a bool:

```
cPassword.ShouldReturn = () => {

    Login();
    return true;

};
```

<strike>Also note that since ShouldReturn is a property of a delegate type, the best practice is to assign the value, not add to it like you would do with events ("+=").</strike>

Comment: Thanks, such a simple fix, as always. Though it didn't like being assigned as you suggested, guess that's a protected feature and I'd need to create my own EntryElement class.

Comment: Glad I helped. I am sorry for the assignment, I didn't actually check it in code. If it is actually an event and not a property, please let me know so that I can correct my answer.

Comment: The error that you get is 'MonoTouch.Dialog.EntryElement.ShouldReturn' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -= when used outside of the type 'MonoTouch.Dialog.EntryElement' (CS0070). The Basis of my original attempt was based on Miguels answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634752/trying-to-add-event-to-shouldreturn-on-an-entry-element), it was the missing 'return [bool]' that was causing me trouble >_<